# Want to dual boot MBP with Linux

Tags: dual-boot, distribution-choice, distributions, macintosh

I just upgraded to a 1tb HDD in my MacBook Pro (non-retina) and would like to dual boot from OS X to a linux distro.

I'd like to find out a few things so I can be better prepared and informed for this process.

1) Partitioning...  Should I...
a) Use BootCamp to create the second partition?
b) Use Disk Utility to resizes and create the second partition?
c) Create the partition from within the Linux live USB or DVD?

2) Which distro is recommended?  I've used both Mint and Ubuntu in the past and definitely prefer distros based on Debian that use `apt-get` as opposed to the others like SUSE.

3) I've heard that it's a pain to get the wifi to work, is that true?  If so, how to I enable the drivers?  Is there an `apt-get` command I can use in order to do so?

4) Other than the wifi difficulties is there anything else I should be aware of and be prepared for?

Comment: Hi Evan, and welcome to U&L. Unfortunately, the odds seem pretty slim that any one person is able to answer all of this, and at least your second question ("which distro is recommended?") also appears primarily opinion-based to me. You'd be better off breaking this up into multiple questions for the unrelated parts and rephrasing the questions to be quantifiable. For example, rather than "should I (a), (b) or (c)?", you might try to phrase the question like "for purpose (x), what are the relative advantages and disadvantages of (a), (b) and (c)?". Which technique you *should* use is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally create the partition through the live DVD/USB, using gParted or cfdisk, to set up the secondary partition before install. As for a distro recommendation it really varies user from user, I personally prefer the likes of Arch Linux due to the gratifying feeling of building it up and making it unique e.g. making it yours. But as you're a beginner and prefer Debian why not go with Debian?

I'm not a mac person myself but my friend has been running Debian on his Macbook for years without issue, it is the most stable distro you'll find, and it should support your WiFi drivers, however if you want something simple and easy to use go with Mint.